# fix ms compiler c code to compile in gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Hello, I have some very basic understanding of c/c++ language after reading one c and one c++ book to about a half each for over 15 years ago.

Around that time also, in 1998-9ish, I've bought a book "Black Art of 3D Game Programming, writing your own high-speed 3d polygon video games in c". Publisher - Waite, author - Andre LaMothe. 
It positions itself so that you don't have to know c as a prerequisite, in order to study this book. I really wanted to learn it then, but got involved in other things and distracted by other projects. Around that time, I've found out about several other languages. I tried perl, and really liked it. I learned it's basics fairly quickly and wrote my first big project in 3 months + 3 more months, fixing and fine tuning it, in perl. Since then, I've started to learn more and improve in perl, so didn't really have time for c.

The wish to learn game and graphics programming never left me, so I've decided to return to that game programming book. I know, that you can learn OpenGL, or WebGL now, but that book, appears to me, has many low level concepts, that, if you don't learn, you will not become as good for game programming, as you could, however, this book requires you to have MS C/C++ 7.0 compiler. Since then, I've moved to linux (over 5 years ago) and don't want to go back to windows. Also, whatever I learn, I would like it to be crossplatform, so I'd rather figure out how to modify the book's code to compile in gcc, then install MS C/C++ 7.0 compiler under wine, or in a windows virtual machine.

In the book:

```
//input driven event loops

//includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void main(void){
    int done=0,
        number,
        num_tries=0,
        guess;

//removed far from the unsigned line, because compiler complains:
//error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
//      unsigned int far *clock = (unsigned int far *)0x0000046CL;  //clock pointer
        unsigned int *clock = (unsigned int *)0x0000046CL;  //clock pointer

        //section 1
        printf("\nI'm thinking of a number from 1-100.");
        printf("\nTry and guess it!\n");

        srand(*clock);
        number = 1 + rand() % 100;

        printf("test");
}
```

The code, in the book, as above, except that the commented unsigned line is the original, but uncommented is modified. After changing the unsigned line, it compiles with gcc file_name.c, but when the execution of the compiled binary gets to the srand line, the program quits with a segmentation fault. I guess, the "far" thing has something to do with the ms compiler, and, maybe the whole line, getting the clock pointer. Any suggestions on how I can fix it?

### Updated:

OK, so I understand that the clock pointer line is useless in modern programming and I should use time.h instead, so I've changed the clock pointer to a time() function. Also, I've added the return and int to the main function, as was suggested. Here is the new code:

```
//input driven event loops

//includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
    int done=0,
        number,
        num_tries=0,
        guess;

    //section 1
    printf("\nI'm thinking of a number from 1-100.");
    printf("\nTry and guess it!\n");

    srand(time(NULL));
    number = 1 + rand() % 100;

    return(0);
}
```

It works fine without segmentation faults now. Thank You.

Comment: If you're trying to run this on Linux then it's not going to work.

Comment: @PaulR Isn't that the very premise of the question?

Comment: By now you should use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` for the main function with an accordant `return` statement.

Comment: It's not an MS thing, but rather an old Intel thing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer

Comment: @mjs: it's not totally clear (to me at least) whether the OP is currently trying to do this with gcc on Windows or gcc on Linux.

Comment: He has "moved to linux" and wants to compile on gcc and then maybe later "install MS compiler under Wine or in a Windows VM". Seems clear.

Comment: It's not going to work on windows, either.

Comment: @mjs: OK - well the comment remains valid - trying to read the hard-coded clock address is obviously not going to work on Linux.

Comment: @alain: well it might work on Windows 95. ;-)

Comment: @PaulR Didn't Windows 95 already use 'protected mode', or was 2000/XP the first?

Comment: @alain: I could be wrong but I think Windows NT was the first, from which Windows 2000 was later derived. Windows 95/98 were pretty crude.

Comment: @PaulR, Yes, that's possible. Ahh, I feel so nostalgic.. :-)

Comment: If I remember correctly, you could do direct memory access up until Windows 98. I remember writing a program which fiddled with direct access of the classic "parallel port" in Windows 2000, and I had to use some tricks to bypass the "protected mode".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`far` is a non-standard C keyword. Unless you are sure it's needed, forget about it.

From the code, it's a simple guess number game, `clock` is supposed to provide a seed for the random generator. `0x0000046CL` is, again, some non-portable code that causes segmentation fault.

For simple uses, use the current time as the seed instead.

```
srand(time(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

well, that's the deprecated way to get time from clock.

use

```
srand(time(NULL)); //#include <time.h>
```

it will give you current time,
I guess that code of yours has some security issues